# Hide MasterView - UISplitViewController with UITabController and UITableView

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view controller that contains a tab controller that contains a table view in each of its tab items - all on the "master side".  The table view gives a list of items that the user can select from in order to control what is displayed on the "detail side".

I am trying to move the master table view off the screen after the user has made a selection - rather than the user needing to tap the screen to dismiss the master table view.

I am using the code below.  As the code comments indicate it leaves an translucent "shadow" in place of the master side table view.  What else do I need to be doing to completely move the master side table view off the screen.

```
- (void)hideSidebarNavPanel
{
    /*  This almost works - in that it moves the table view off the screen but leaves a "shadow" in its place. 
        This occurs whether we modify the frame for the tabBarView or the masterTableView or the masterView - or for all 3.
        It seems that there is something else sitting below both of these that also needs to have its frame modified.
        The question is what?
     */

    UIView *masterView = self.view;
    CGRect masterViewFrame = masterView.frame;
    masterViewFrame.origin.x -= masterViewFrame.size.width;

    NSArray *controllers = self.splitViewController.viewControllers;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];

    UIView *tabBarView = tabBarController.view;
    CGRect tabBarFrame = tabBarView.frame;
    tabBarFrame.origin.x -= tabBarFrame.size.width;

//    UIViewController *masterNavigationController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
//    UIView *masterTableView = masterNavigationController.view;
//    CGRect masterTableViewFrame = masterTableView.frame;
//    masterTableViewFrame.origin.x -= masterTableViewFrame.size.width;       

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"showView" context:NULL];
    masterView.frame = masterViewFrame;
    tabBarView.frame = tabBarFrame;
    //masterTableView.frame = masterTableViewFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```